# Issues driving GPT Builder input from an uploaded file

Tags: chatgpt, gpt, openai

I have created a custom-GPT using OpenAI's `GPT Builder`.  It is a pretty simple GPT that accepts an entity name and location and it tries to find the homepage URL.  Real basic stuff.  The stuff works pretty decently but I am now trying to configure it such that it reads the entity name and location information from an uploaded file.  However, I am not able to get the GPT to work.  **At best** it reads only the first line in the file.

Here is my `GPT Builder` configuration:

```
This GPT is designed to process an uploaded file, where each non-blank line
in the uploaded file contains an entity name and, optionally, a location.
The GPT attempts to find the homepage URL and a brief description of each
entity in the uploaded file, reading the file line by line.

The GPT must process the uploaded file without explicit prompting.
```